# Trying to convert jQuery autocomplete js.coffee to Mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, jquery-autocomplete

In a Rails 4.0.0 app, I have been following this guide to autocomplete https://gist.github.com/map7/1347080 and want to convert the javacsript to jQuery mobile which doesn't like $(document).ready.

Here is the original coffee javascript

```
$(document).ready ->
     $('#post_user_name').autocomplete
             source: "/autocomplete/users"
             select: (event,ui) -> $("#post_user_id").val(ui.item.id)
```

I have attempted to convert this to mobile using the follow but I get reserved word "function" error.

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () ->
        $('#autocomplete_employee_name').autocomplete
           source: "/autocomplete/employees"
           minLength: 3
           select: (event,ui) -> $("#autocomplete_employee_id").val(ui.item.id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "function" is not used in Coffeescript to define a function. Use the arrow only:

```
$(document).bind "mobileinit", ->
    $('#autocomplete_employee_name').autocomplete
       source: "/autocomplete/employees"
       minLength: 3
       select: (event,ui) -> $("#autocomplete_employee_id").val(ui.item.id)
```

BTW: You can validate your Coffeescripts in realtime [here, where I added your code](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3a%24%28document%29.bind%20%22mobileinit%22,%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%24%28%27#autocomplete_employee_name%27%29.autocomplete%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20source%3a%20%22/autocomplete/employees%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20minLength%3a%203%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20select%3a%20%28event,ui%29%20-%3E%20%24%28%22#autocomplete_employee_id%22%29.val%28ui.item.id%29), so you can see it is fine now.

Comment: This produces an error, missing ). Is the comma here intended? Should it be this? '$(document).bind("mobileinit") ->'

Comment: No, that bracket should be closed at the end, after the first callback function. Or, as updated in my example, simply omit it.

Comment: This solution works if I use document.ready but not bind "mobileinit". The app is jQuery mobile only.